# Closest Date to a given date - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle (SQL) - I have 3 available dates in a month (1st, 10th and 25th). I need a query to find out the closest among the 3 dates based on the date of executing my query. For e.g, when i run the query on 4th, i should get 10th as my result, when i run on 12th, the result should be 25th and when i run on 27th, the result should be the 01st of next month.
I am struggling with the logic. Please help..

Comment: Which version of the database?

Comment: Always these 3 dates? Use a `case` expression.

Comment: How come 27th is closer to 1st following month instead of 25th? '

Comment: I think he means the closest date that isn't past one of his three determined dates. Since the 27th is past the 25th, you'd go to the 1st of the next month.

Comment: yes that is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is much more efficient and simpler than the other solutions.

```
WITH
    possible_dates
    AS
        -- generate the three available dates for the current month
        (SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM') available_date
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM') + 9
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM') + 24
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
           FROM DUAL),
    delta
    AS
        -- calculate the distance of those available dates
        (SELECT (available_date - SYSDATE) diff, available_date
           FROM possible_dates)
SELECT *
  FROM delta
 WHERE diff = (SELECT MIN (diff)
                 FROM delta
                WHERE diff >= 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with
     inputs ( dt ) as (
       select to_date( '03/24/2015 11:30:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select to_date( '08/03/2016 07:15:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select to_date( '02/29/2016 22:30:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select dt,
       case when extract(day from dt) < 10 then trunc(dt, 'mm') + interval  '9' day
            when extract(day from dt) < 25 then trunc(dt, 'mm') + interval '24' day
            else add_months(trunc(dt, 'mm'), 1)
       end  as next_std_dt
from   inputs;

DT                   NEXT_STD_DT       
-------------------  -------------------
03/24/2015 11:30:00  03/25/2015 00:00:00
08/03/2016 07:15:00  08/10/2016 00:00:00
02/29/2016 22:30:00  03/01/2016 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH mytable(dt) AS
  (SELECT '01'
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT '10'
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT '25'
   FROM dual),
     given_dates AS
  (SELECT Trunc (To_date (dt || To_char(sysdate, 'MMYYYY'), 'DDMMYYYY')) dt,
          Trunc(sysdate) cdate
   FROM mytable),
     comp AS
  (SELECT cdate,
          CASE
              WHEN ABS (cdate - dt) < ABS (cdate - Add_months (dt, 1)) THEN dt
              ELSE Add_months (dt, 1)
          END dt_comp
   FROM given_dates)
SELECT dt_comp closest_date
FROM
  (SELECT dt_comp,
          rank() OVER (
                       ORDER BY ABS (cdate - dt_comp)) rn
   FROM comp)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If using PL SQL is an option, then use the query as following:

```
`DECLARE
   curr_month        CHAR(2);
   curr_year         CHAR(4);
   future_date       DATE;
BEGIN
   select to_char(sysdate, 'MM') INTO curr_month from dual;
   select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') INTO curr_year from dual;
   future_date := TO_DATE('12' ||  curr_month || curr_year, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
   IF (SYSDATE > future_date) THEN
        {..whatever you want to do...}
   ELSIF (SYSDATE > future_date2) THEN
        {..whatever you want to do...}
   END IF;
END;`
```

Comment: Thank you very much